# Importing Excel function into my module

Tags: excel, vba, function, import, reference

I'm working in VBA, Excel specifically, and trying to use the SQRT (square root) function.  I'm writing a module but don't know how to do import the SQRT function so my function can use it.

Comment: `WorksheetFunction.SQRT()` or just `Sqr()`.  See [HERE](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/sqr.php)

Comment: Being a self-taught vba noob I've found google to be very useful. In my case I googled "Square root vba" and got the very page that scott has linked for you.

Answer (score 0):

this will return a square root:

```
MsgBox 4 ^ (1 / 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer, 
Hoping this helps.

```
Function myFunction(rng As Range) As Double
    Dim i As Double
    i = rng.Value
    myFunction = Sqr(i)
    'this function returns the square root of the value of i
End Function
```

With a search and no effort [Google show me](https://www.google.com/search?q=how%20to%20use%20sqrt%20into%20vba%20macro%20excel&oq=how%20to%20use%20sqrt%20into%20vba%20macro%20excel%20&aqs=chrome..69i57.8359j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8) this

1: [MS Excel: How to use the SQR Function (WS)](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/sqr.php)

2: [Create SquareRoot Function in VBA - MrExcel.com](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/648601-create-squareroot-function-visual-basic-applications.html)

And many more.